# React Native Android Local Images Don't Render

Tags: react-native

I've made tons of googling and didn't encounter anything about the issue I've faced. Application and images work fine on iOS. I tried everything, minifying images, changing directories, creating drawable folders and some similar possible solutions; none of them worked.

**Problem**

My application renders 11 image per swiper page, and there are five pages, 55 images total. 5 of them full screen background images with `width:null, height:null` and `flex:1`. When I run it, there were only 2 background images rendered and others failed (a grey screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coding Native Android (via Android Studio & Java) I came across the problem itself. Even native Android doesn't render images bigger than 4096x4096* (I believe these numbers have units of dpi's).

**Solution**

Resizing images solved the problem on both native Android and React Native. Simply change the resolutions.